# Memory Garbage on vector.erase of pointer

Tags: c++, memory, vector

i would like to know if is safe to do this:

```
std::vector<int*> v;
...
//no deleting
v.erase(v.begin());
```

With safe i mean that by doing this, we are not creating garbage, and so that `std::vector<T>::erase` is calling himself `delete pointer;`, or if instead i should have done manually the deleting:

```
std::vector<int*> v;
...
delete v[0];
v.erase(v.begin());
```

Comment: So you basically want to know if `vector` calls `delete` when you use a pointer type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard containers, like `std::vector`, containing *raw pointers* DO NOT automatically `delete` the things that the pointers are pointing at, when removing the pointers from the containers.  If you want that, store *smart pointers* instead, ie `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: ok, thank you so much